# Are there any prominent non-fan dubs of "A Cruel Angel's Thesis" in other languages?

Tags: theme-song, neon-genesis-evangelion

Remembering that there was a dubbed version of one of the OP's from the 2003 FMA [in Cantonese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tndHYimcaX0), that seems to have been popular in Hong Kong (judging from YouTube), I wanted to know if there was anything similar for NGE's "A Cruel Angel's Thesis".

I found [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46_LCjeODEA) on YouTube - there was at least one other upload of a song with the same voice, and I also found [a set of lyrics](http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/562139787.html) that approximately correspond to what is sung there. However, I haven't really been able to locate the singer's identity from a quick Google search. Moreover, there doesn't seem to be mention of a singer or a dub of the song on the Chinese Wikipedia, although perhaps my Chinese skills aren't just good enough for me to pick this up. I also managed to find a different recording with a female voice that was in Cantonese, but had different lyrics, which makes me somewhat suspicious as to the existence of an "official" dub. (It's of course possible though that a song will have multiple covers in the same language by prominent artists, as happened with a popular Angela Aki song.)

I also looked up the Cantonese dub of the first episode of NGE, and the one I found kept the OP in the original Japanese.

Is there an actual, reasonably prominent dub of "A Cruel Angel's Thesis" in languages other than Japanese? I'm particularly interested in whether or not there are any Chinese dubs. I'm looking for something comparable to Eason Chan's dub of the FMA OP, in the sense that it should be reasonably "prominent" and done professionally and not, say, a amateur fan-made production.

Comment: In a sense, you could also say that I'm looking for dubbed OPs that replace the original, as in the FMA case.

Comment: The [Chinese dubbed OP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8FXIKYy5ZA) is quite prominent in that every Chinese who has watched EVA has heard this song that gives one goosebumps. It is widely known as 鞠萍姐姐版, but it is not sung by her.

Answer (score 5):

There's also an OP sung in Mandarin, but it looks like my old link to that has been removed from Youtube by Bandai.

There's this [Spanish Full Opening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwZF7SpG5rM) that I believe is sung by Jessica Toledo.

And this appears to be (the song at least) a [Korean version of the short OP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciUQc_7qR5o).